# Jquery click event (for list items) stacking

Tags: jquery

So after trying various methods such as if statements and removing classes I finally give up. I cant think of an elegant solution to fix my code.

The events dont reset when I click on a different list item. Instead it somehow accumulates. What is going on here?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$( ".home" ).click(function() {
$( this ).toggleClass( "item-active" );
$( ".block-1" ).toggleClass( "blocks" );
$( ".b1" ).toggleClass( "blockss" );
  $( ".content" ).toggleClass( "content-removed" );
});
$( ".products" ).click(function() {
$( this ).toggleClass( "item-active" );
$( ".block-2" ).toggleClass( "blocks" );
$( ".b2" ).toggleClass( "blockss" );
  $( ".content" ).toggleClass( "content-removed" );
});});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bk38w/87/

I made a jsfiddle and copied the code there. You can see the problem live there.

I would appreciate insight.

Comment: And what is the problem? What needs to happen?

Comment: Is there a reason why you choose not to have one function for all of the menu items? Just checking

Comment: @BojanPetkovski if you click on Home and when that is active on Products both are active. I want the previous item to reset to its default state.

Comment: @stack_bloom if you click on home and products both are active. Actually the previous shouldnt be active if a new item is clicked

Comment: You want that functionality only for home and products? And what about the rest of the menu items?

Comment: I would actually do one menu function. That clears all the other items of classes in the menu and add on the current. I'm not in a good position to write it at this moment, but will do when I get home if nobody haven't done it.

Comment: Do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/bk38w/89/ ?

Comment: @BojanPetkovski actually for the others too.  I added ..... because Im not sure of any names yet.

Comment: @BojanPetkovski yes! what exactly did you do here? Im studying it now.

Comment: Basically you need to make same classes for all items and change them basically on what have you clicked. Only one click function is needed. As soon as I get home I will help you out making it :)

Comment: @BojanPetkovski  Hi I updated my code with your fix. Works really nice! This is the sub issue im facing with the content toggling everytime. I forgot to add it in my original question http://jsfiddle.net/bk38w/92/

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your code to only use one method instead of having separate classes for each menu. Cleaner `html` `css` `js`, also using less classes.

When it comes to the css you should think about this one below. It used to be `.blockss`, now you just change the css of `.b1` items if their parent has `.blocks`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/75gs6md9/1/)

Hope this helps and that you understand what it's doing. You could actually even clean up your html a bit more, i.e. you could remove the `<div class="b1">` and set the `.b1` class on the `<a>` and make it `display: block;` but that's just if you really want to clean up :)

```
.blocks .b1 {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

html

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#" class="trigger" data-id="home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="trigger" data-id="products">Products</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div data-sub-id="home" class="block">
        <div class="b1"><a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="b1"><a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="b1"><a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-sub-id="products" class="block">
        <div class="b1"><a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="b1"><a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="b1"><a href="#">Link 4</a>
        </div>
        <div class="b1"><a href="#">Link 5</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

js

```
$(".trigger").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        ul = $this.parents('ul'),
        dataId = $this.data('id'),
        subMenu = $this.parents('nav').find('[data-sub-id="' + dataId + '"]'),
        subMenus = $this.parents('nav').find('.block');

    //remove classes from all items
    ul.find('li a').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('item-active');
    });

    subMenus.each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('blocks');       
    });

    //add classes to this item
    $this.addClass('item-active');
    subMenu.addClass('blocks');
});
```

Comment: I forgot to add the content. Basically what happens also is that the content triggers too. I only want the content to appear again if the menu items are deselected http://jsfiddle.net/bk38w/92/

Comment: something I tried just now. Im going to show you the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/pevnuL1y/2/

Comment: @Steve Is the content suppose to change on each for its each menu item? I mean like if you press "home" you want the "home content" to show, if you press "products" it shows the "products content"?